# How do I change the length of the secondary bone segments with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances, vector, splines

I am trying to make spines generated on a Bezier curve and have it 95% working. The rotations are all correct and the scaling is how I like it BUT I cannot figure out how to change the length of the secondary segments (smaller horizontal bones) to match the scaling factor of the main segments. I need to somehow sample the radius of the main bone segment mesh, then add a slight value to that, convert it to a vector format and then use it as input for the start and end coordinates of the secondary segments. But I am at a loss for how to do so. [image: This is my current output, as you can see the main segments scaled and adhere to the spinal cord but the length of the secondary segments does not change][image: This is my current node layout for generating these spines. I hope it is organized enough and sorry about that one stray along the top and left.]

Answer (score 0):

When instancing, you can use the radius (or other calculation) to change the instance scales.

[image]